# Django - suddenly logging to (runserver) console

Tags: python, django, logging

I can't figure out why `Django` started to log into the console. When I run `django` server (in `PyCharm`), there are log entries in the same console.

I've recently installed my fork of `pysendpulse` but it may be a coincidence.

```
INFO     [2019-04-08 00:59:05,331]  Initialization SendPulse REST API Class
DEBUG    [2019-04-08 00:59:05,331]  Try to get security token from 'MEMCACHED'
DEBUG    [2019-04-08 00:59:05,331]  Got: 'some string'
INFO     [2019-04-08 00:59:05,775]  Initialization SendPulse REST API Class
DEBUG    [2019-04-08 00:59:05,775]  Try to get security token from 'MEMCACHED'
DEBUG    [2019-04-08 00:59:05,775]  Got: 'some string'
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
DEBUG    [2019-04-08 00:59:06,025]  (0.001) 
            SELECT c.relname, c.relkind
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v')
                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid); args=None
DEBUG    [2019-04-08 00:59:06,026]  (0.000) SELECT "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name" FROM "django_migrations"; args=()
April 08, 2019 - 00:59:06
Django version 2.1.7, using settings 'p.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

For example the first line is logged from this:

```
logging.info("Initialization SendPulse REST API Class")
```

**settings.LOGGING**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{asctime} {levelname} {module} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'local_file_debug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOG_PATH, 'django_debug.log'),
            'maxBytes': DEFAULT_LOG_SIZE,
            'backupCount': 0,
        },
        'local_file': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOG_PATH, 'django.log'),
            'maxBytes': DEFAULT_LOG_SIZE,
            'backupCount': 0,
        },
        'pipedrive': {
            'level': 'DEBUG' if DEBUG else 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(LOG_PATH, 'pipedrive.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'maxBytes': DEFAULT_LOG_SIZE,
            'backupCount': 0,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['local_file_debug' if DEBUG else 'local_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'pipedrive': {
            'handlers': ['pipedrive'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

Do you know where could be the problem?

**EDIT**

**shell_plus**

**print(logging.root)**

```
<RootLogger root (DEBUG)>
```

**print(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)**

```
{'amqp': <Logger amqp (DEBUG)>, 'kombu.connection': <Logger kombu.connection (DEBUG)>, 'kombu': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f32045565c0>, 'celery': <Logger celery (DEBUG)>, 'celery.task': <Logger celery.task (DEBUG)>, 'celery.worker': <Logger celery.worker (DEBUG)>, 'kombu.common': <Logger kombu.common (DEBUG)>, 'celery.utils.dispatch.signal': <Logger celery.utils.dispatch.signal (DEBUG)>, 'celery.utils.dispatch': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f3203609898>, 'celery.utils': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f3203609978>, 'celery.app.builtins': <Logger celery.app.builtins (DEBUG)>, 'celery.app': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f32036e6c88>, 'celery.app.base': <Logger celery.app.base (DEBUG)>, 'django.template': <Logger django.template (DEBUG)>, 'django': <Logger django (DEBUG)>, 'concurrent.futures': <Logger concurrent.futures (DEBUG)>, 'concurrent': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f3203267940>, 'asyncio': <Logger asyncio (DEBUG)>, 'django.db.backends': <Logger django.db.backends (DEBUG)>, 'django.db': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f3202855668>, 'django.request': <Logger django.request (DEBUG)>, 'django.server': <Logger django.server (DEBUG)>, 'pipedrive': <Logger pipedrive (DEBUG)>, 'django.security.csrf': <Logger django.security.csrf (DEBUG)>, 'django.security': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f32025823c8>, 'django.db.backends.schema': <Logger django.db.backends.schema (DEBUG)>, 'urllib3.util.retry': <Logger urllib3.util.retry (DEBUG)>, 'urllib3.util': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31feafb4e0>, 'urllib3': <Logger urllib3 (DEBUG)>, 'urllib3.connection': <Logger urllib3.connection (DEBUG)>, 'urllib3.response': <Logger urllib3.response (DEBUG)>, 'urllib3.connectionpool': <Logger urllib3.connectionpool (DEBUG)>, 'urllib3.poolmanager': <Logger urllib3.poolmanager (DEBUG)>, 'requests': <Logger requests (DEBUG)>, 'superfakura.api': <Logger superfakura.api (DEBUG)>, 'superfakura': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fe527208>, 'p.apps.apis.superfaktura.utils': <Logger p.apps.apis.superfaktura.utils (DEBUG)>, 'p.apps.apis.superfaktura': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fe51c7b8>, 'p.apps.apis': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fe51c860>, 'p.apps': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fe527470>, 'p': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fe527588>, 'p.apps.apis.superfaktura.models': <Logger p.apps.apis.superfaktura.models (DEBUG)>, 'django_bootstrap_breadcrumbs.templatetags.django_bootstrap_breadcrumbs': <Logger django_bootstrap_breadcrumbs.templatetags.django_bootstrap_breadcrumbs (DEBUG)>, 'django_bootstrap_breadcrumbs.templatetags': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fdece2b0>, 'django_bootstrap_breadcrumbs': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fdece2e8>, 'PIL.Image': <Logger PIL.Image (DEBUG)>, 'PIL': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fdea29e8>, 'prompt_toolkit': <Logger prompt_toolkit (DEBUG)>, 'parso.python.diff': <Logger parso.python.diff (DEBUG)>, 'parso.python': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fc597668>, 'parso': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x7f31fc597be0>, 'parso.cache': <Logger parso.cache (DEBUG)>, 'TerminalIPythonApp': <Logger TerminalIPythonApp (WARNING)>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've recently installed my fork of `pysendpulse` but it may be a
>   coincidence.

Depending on how/where you forked it, this is not a coincidence.
The original `pysendpulse` calls [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) in the package's [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/sendpulse/sendpulse-rest-api-python/blob/master/pysendpulse/pysendpulse.py#L27).

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

The purpose of `basicConfig` is setting up ...

> ... basic configuration for the logging system by creating a
>   `StreamHandler` with a default `Formatter` and adding it to the root
>   logger.

This is done [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1980-L2002).

Since you configure your `django` logger to propagate (which is the default)

```
'propagate': True,
```

the log records are not only handled by your dedicated logger, but are also sent up the chain of ancestors, ending up with the `root` logger.

Without importing `pysendpulse`, the `root` logger does not have a handler attached and is set to the default level `WARNING`; the log records get "lost" (on the level of the `root`logger).
But the call to `logging.basicConfig` in `pysendpulse` attaches the `StreamHandler` to your `root` logger and sets it to level `DEBUG`, hence you see the messages on your console.

As for solutions, you could either disable propagation on your `django` logger

```
'propagate': False,
```

remove the `StreamHandler` from the `root` logger

```
logging.getLogger().removeHandler(logging.getLogger().handlers[0])
```

or, since you apparently forked `pysendpulse`, consider removing the `logging.basicConfig` call from the `__init__.py` module.

Comment: Thank you @shmee, I used the third option and it partially works but, which is very weird, there are still the last two log entries from my example (the migration ones). The others disappeared. It would be a huge coincidence if there were two totally different sources of this problem because I've never experienced such behavior.

Comment: Moreover, if I try the second option, Django doesn't log migrations anymore but pysendpulse do. There must be a common source of the problem I think.

Comment: Can you show me the loggers that are configured in the context of `runserver`? `print(logging.root)` and `print(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)`.

Comment: I've added output from `shell_plus` to the bottom of the question (hope it's ok).

Comment: Yeah, thanks ... and woah ... that is *a lot* of loggers you have there. I'd be interested to see how many handlers the root logger has: `print(logging.root.handlers)`. Is this output with or without the `logging.basicConfig` call in `pysendpulse.__init__.py`? Which one is the `pysendpulse` logger that logs django migrations if the root handler is removed? I'd like to see `print(logging.getlogger(<pysendpulse logger name>).parent)` and `print(logging.getlogger('django').parent)` as well please. Very strange that an unrelated logger should receive the messages, tbh.

Comment: It even logs in shell_plus when I use TAB. I'm going to check those loggers.

Comment: It's definitely this line `logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)` when I comment it, everything works as before.

Comment: @Milano That's the one in the `pysendpulse.__init__.py` right? Didn't you state in your first comment that commenting that line (the third option I proposed, although I recommended to remove it) only worked partially?

Comment: I did, sorry, don't know why it works correctly now :)

Comment: @Milano :D witchcraft and black magic! Cool that it worked in the end. I was seriously beginning to wonder which other package might set up logging besides `pysendpulse`.